# Building Google Analytics package in ASP.NET Core 5.0

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client, asp.net-core

I am trying to include Google Analytics API [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Analytics.v3/) in my MVC 6 application. I've tried to include all the dependencies or to let it install trough NuGet Package Manager. In either case, when i build the solution, I get an error: `Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ProjectName.ASP.NET Core 5.0`

Any idea what dependencies I need to include for it to build in ASP.Net Core 5.0?

Here is what i have in my `project.json` file:

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "Microsoft.Net.Http": "2.2.28.0",
    "Microsoft.Bcl": "1.1.9.0",
    "Microsoft.Bcl.Build": "1.0.21.0",
    "Microsoft.Bcl.Async": "1.0.168.0",
    "Google.Apis.Analytics.v3": "1.9.0.1100"
},
...
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies": {
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {
        "dependencies": {
            "Newtonsoft.Json": "6.0.8.0"
        }
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue to the one described here: [Problems with RavenDB.Client reference in asp.net 5.0 project.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423123/problems-with-ravendb-client-reference-in-asp-net-5-0-project-json)

Adapting my answer from there:

The problem is that you referencing `Google.Apis.Analytics.v3` in the top level dependencies node in `project.json`. That means that those dependencies are applicable to both Desktop CLR (`aspnet50`) and CoreCLR (`aspnetcore50`).

When you build an ASPNET 5 project, all configurations are built, not just the "active" one. Mostly sure `Google.Apis.Analytics.v3` works only with the Desktop CLR so move it under a dependencies node under that configuration.

```
"dependencies": {
    ....
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies" : {
            "Google.Apis.Analytics.v3": "1.9.0.1100"
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {}
}
```

Then you might have to either use some conditional blocks in your code (`#if ASPNET50`) or remove CoreCLR all together.
Then you might have to either use some conditional blocks in your code (#if ASPNET50) or remove CoreCLR all together.

Comment: I finally understand the [Frameworks](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/Project.json-file#frameworks) section's docs.

Comment: Thank you fro your help, but I was wondering if there are dependencies that can make GA to compile in CoreCLR.

Comment: That is something that only GA authors can figure out :) It is not just the dependencies that are different but also the code