# Problems with RavenDB.Client reference in asp.net 5.0 project.json

Tags: c#, ravendb, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a RavenApiController with the new ASP.NET 5.0 (aka Asp.Net vNext) stuff and can't seem to get the RavenDB.Client references to work at all.

The error I get is

> **Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Raven' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SharedIO.ASP.NET Core 5.0 RavenApiController.cs 3**

My project.json is as follows

```
{
"webroot": "wwwroot",
"version": "1.0.0-*",
"exclude": [
    "wwwroot"
],
"packExclude": [
    "**.kproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
],
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2",
    "RavenDB.Client": "3.0.3599",
    "SharedIOModel": "1.0.0-*"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {},
    "aspnetcore50": {}
}
```

}

The code for RavenApiController.cs which fails to build on the third line begins as:

```
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
    using Raven.Client;
    using Raven.Client.Document;;

    namespace SharedIO.Controllers
    {
        [RequireHttps]
        public abstract class RavenAPIController : Controller
        {
            public IDocumentStore Store
            {
                get { return LazyDocStore.Value; }
            }
```

Totally stumped.

For what it's worth intellisense seems to be able to find the reference just fine and I don't get an error until I actually 'build solution.

Also Intellisense shows me that (for example) Raven.Client.Document.IDocumentStore is 'Available' in ASP.NET 5.0 but 'Not Available' in  'ASP.NET Core 5.0'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you referencing `RavenDB.Client` in the top level dependencies node in `project.json`. That means that those dependencies are applicable to both Desktop CLR (`aspnet50`) and CoreCLR (`aspnetcore50`).

When you build an ASPNET 5 project, all configurations are built, not just the "active" one. Mostly sure `RavenDB.Client` works only with the Desktop CLR so move it under a dependencies node under that configuration.

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta2",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta2",
    "SharedIOModel": "1.0.0-*"
},
"frameworks": {
    "aspnet50": {
        "dependencies" : {
            "RavenDB.Client": "3.0.3599",
        }
    },
    "aspnetcore50": {}
}
```

Then you might have to either use some conditional blocks in your code (`#if ASPNET50`) or remove CoreCLR all together.

Comment: Wow that worked a treat. Thanks. 

I ended up removing the CoreCLR one altogether and left the references at the 'top' level and it builds just fine now. 


Worries me a little that I don't really understand the difference between aspnet50 and  aspnetcore50 nor why Raven DB only complies under 'Desktop CLR' but... hopefully these mysteries will become clear with time. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it seems that removing the `"aspnetcore50": {}` would be the better solution.

Comment: To understand CoreCLR, take a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2014/11/18/what-is-net-core-5-and-asp-net-5-within-net-2015-preview.aspx)