# ASP.NET 5 with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver, asp.net-core

Trying to get an ASP.NET 5 website integrated with the MongoDB C# driver but running into a few issues.

First of all, the examples listed here http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/ are all flagged as obsolete.

Secondly, I'm getting really weird compile errors (type or namespace could not be found) when I try and build even though everything looks OK in the IDE.

Here's my very basic HomeController.cs

```
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System;

namespace Docker.Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private AppSettings _appSettings;

        public HomeController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _appSettings = serviceProvider.GetService<AppSettings>();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var server = new MongoClient(_appSettings.MongoConnection).GetServer();
            var database = server.GetDatabase(_appSettings.MongoDatabase);

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Main question is can I use the C# MongoDB driver with ASP.NET 5?

Using Visual Studio 2015 preview and targeting KRE version **KRE-CoreCLR-x86.1.0.0-beta2**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with RavenDB.Client reference in asp.net 5.0 project.json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423123/problems-with-ravendb-client-reference-in-asp-net-5-0-project-json)

Comment: Please see the duplicate question, I think you are having the same issue - MongoDB is only available for Desktop CLR (`aspnet50`). Basically, you code builds fine for DesktopCLR and fails for CoreCLR.

Comment: You cannot reference it from the coreclr unless the package has been built with coreclr support.  That is something I'm sure we'll see happen as aspnet5 gets closer to RTM.  You can however still use it with aspnet5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C# Driver is not supported in CoreCLR but is supported in full CLR451 mode.

I created a sample project using VS2015 CTP

project.json

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "mongocsharpdriver": "1.10.0.0"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
namespace MongoDBvNext
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            var client = new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient("");
            var server = client.GetServer();
            var db = server.GetDatabase("samples");
            var samples = db.GetCollection<Sample>("samples");
            samples.Insert(new Sample { Name = "sample" });
            var sample = samples.AsQueryable<Sample>().Where(x => x.Name == "Sample").FirstOrDefault();
            if (sample == null)
                Console.WriteLine("id: {0} name: {1} ", sample.Id.ToString(), sample.Name);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Data does not exists");
        }

        public class Sample
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this same answer, Thanks Son!

Answer (score 15):

You can use MongoDB with visual studio 2015 (Updated 10 November).

remove 1 line from project.json;

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { }, // don't forget to remove ','
    "dnxcore50": { } // remove this line
}
```

now you can build your solution without any error or warning.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Men want to use .NET Core version and now it is not possible.

Comment: What is your exact problem, can you give some details?

Comment: We need use dnxcore50 runtime

Comment: Asp.net 5 VS 2015:  

I am getting still this errors(when I use "MongoDB.Driver.Core": "2.2.3"):  
 
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Core 5.0 ...cs 1 Active
and same for BsonDocument.

Tried with "MongoDB.Bson": "2.2.3","MongoDB.Driver": "2.2.3" but same issue,  

Error NU1002 The dependency MongoDB.Driver 2.2.3 in project does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.

Comment: Good news, looks like .NET Core should be supported in MongoDB 2.3 [according to their JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1177).