# dnx build - type or namespace not found. Missing reference?

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, dnx

I have made an empty asp.net web app with the new dnu/dnx/vscode combo of utilities.

It's working fine until I try to add 3.party libraries.

I have tried to add MongoDB with the following cmd:

```
 dnu install MongoDb.Driver
 dnu restore
```

This adds the mongodb dependency to my project.json file:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "MongoDb.Driver": "2.0.0"
  },
  ...
```

but when I try to actually reference mongo, things fail:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
```

VSCode gives me intellisense to add this namespace, but it adds a red squiggle under `MongoDB` and a green one under `Bson`.

when I try to build the project with

```
dnu build
```

it fails with the message

```
C:\source\.....cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MongoDB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

**What am I missing here?**

My `project.json` file is totally untouched - except for the added mongo dependency:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "MongoDb.Driver": "2.0.0"
  },
  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Kestrel --server.urls http://localhost:5001"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },
  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check what frameworks are listed in your `project.json` file and if you need an extra or different dependency for the `coreclr`-ish framework.

Comment: I have added the complete project.json file for reference. I'm not sure how I can know if I need extra or different dependency for the `coreclr`-ish framework. I don't really know what `coreclr`-ish framework is...

Answer (score 1):

You may have to reload the editor as well when adding new dependencies. Command palette -> Reload Window

[Answer on twitter regarding this issue](https://twitter.com/chrisdias/status/595736604699992064)

Edit: Probably not helping you, but this thread may be related. Seems like the MongoDB driver package is hard to get running with som versions of ASP.NET.

Comment: I have already tried every single possible way of restarting, from command palette to power switch, but to no use. :-)  Could it be something specific for the MongoDb nuget package?

Comment: Probably not helping you, but [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28484761/asp-net-5-with-mongodb) may be related. Seems like the MongoDB driver package is hard to get running with som versions of ASP.NET.

Comment: Probably it actually do! The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29973105/11956) seems to do the trick! Thanks!

Comment: Slowmove, I think you should modify your answer to include your comment, since I'm not able to accept the comment as an answer....

Answer (score 1):

That is because MongoDb c# drive doesn't support CoreCLR yet. See [this discussion](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/pull/210). Simply remove the `"dnxcore50": {}` in your `project.json` and it will work.

Previously (Beta5) I got the same error doesn't give the meaning. Now I realize now in ASP.NET 5 Beta8 produce the meaningful error:

> The dependency MongoDB.Driver.Core 2.1.0 in project  does not support framework DNXCore,Version=v5.0.