# Class not recognized by compiler in ASP.NET 5 Class Library (vNext)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I try to create a simple website in ASP.NET 5 vNext. I've created an ASP.NET 5 class library and added some classes that I was already using in another project.

I've a problem with 2 dependencies. The compiler tells me

> The type or namespace name 'FileStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  FlashTools.ASP.NET Core 5.0

And same error for "ICSharpCode" (not part of .NET framework of course)
I've already added System.IO and SharpZipLib (for ICSharpCode class) in my project. Here is my project.json:

```
{
   "version": "1.0.0-*",
   "dependencies": {
      "SharpZipLib": "0.86.0.0"
   },

   "frameworks": {
       "aspnet50": {
           "dependencies": {
           }
       },
       "aspnetcore50": {
           "dependencies": {
               "System.Runtime": "4.0.20.0-beta-22605",
               "System.Linq": "4.0.0.0-beta-22605",
               "System.Threading": "4.0.10.0-beta-22605",
               "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.10.0-beta-22605",
               "System.Globalization": "4.0.10.0-beta-22605",
               "System.IO": "4.0.10-beta-22416"
               // "System.IO": "4.0.10.0-beta-22605",
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Intellisense recognize the class StreamFile or FileMode when for example I type

```
this.stream = new FileStream(this.fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

But the compiler doesn't recognize them.

If I try to use these classes not in my ASP.NET 5 class library but directly in my ASP.NET 5 Web Application, the compiler is ok even though System.IO is not referenced in the project.json file.

Do you have any idea? Is it a problem with the ASP.NET 5 Beta or did I do something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't address this in your question: are you missing a `using` directive?

Comment: Yes I've my using System.IO and it appears in white (not gray) which means for VS that this namespace is used in the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [package search website](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) `FileStream` is in the `System.IO.FileSystem` package which your project doesn't include.

Comment: Ho yeah thanks, I didn't know this website. I don't get why MSDN says it belongs to System.IO https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Now the problem still persists for the SharpZipLib library but it's not part of the .NET framework. I guess I'm stuck now, just have to wait this library become compatible with ASP.NET 5

Comment: You don't have to wait. You will not be able to compile on `Core CLR` until that library becomes available but you can still use `Desktop CLR`. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28423672/149064)

Comment: Haaa ok I understand better now. Thank you Victor